# "Please correct" vs. "Please specify" vs something else - a short phrase to that effect

Tags: phrase-request

From business correspondence:

> Concerning Document D12:
>   Paragraph 1.1 fails to mention the mass flow rate value for the hydraulic seal of the high-pressure ammonia pump (0 kg/hour). **Please correct**.

Would it be better to write "Please specify"? What are the appropriate terse businesslike phrases for the occassion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Please correct" is correct**, given that we did receive a value (the "0 kg/hour" shown in parentheses). We know that 0 is not right, so we want it fixed.

Either phrase could be used, but it depends on what the sentence intends to convey.

If they *could have* included the value but did not, then "please specify" would be appropriate to say "we would like this value, so please give it to us."

However, if they were *supposed* to include the value but did not, then "please correct" would be appropriate to say "you made an error, please fix it."

One phrase's connotation is "please give us some more information," while the other phrase's connotation is "please do what you should have done."

Given the business scenario and my assumption that the mass flow rate is important in this issue, they *should have* included it- justifying the phrase "please correct."

Comment: I agree with this, though I'd add that "Please specify" has a more polite tone, because it asks for the same information without explicitly indicating that a mistake was made. Sometimes in business you get a better result by pretending the other party didn't make a mistake even when both you and they know that they did.

Answer (score 2):

*Please specify* would be better than *Please correct*, although you could say either. *Please correct* implies that they gave the wrong value, but in this case they gave no value. You could also say *Please describe* or *Please clarify*, but I think *Please specify* is the best choice.